I'm trying to figure out how to configure hypercorn logging using a custom logger and format
I managed to make it work after 2 days using the .py configuration file. Here is the code along with a minimal format.


# Hypercorn configuration file

import logging.config



# Server binding options



keyfile="./Certs/app_key.pem"

certfile="./Certs/app_cert.pem"

bind = "0.0.0.0:8443"

insecure_bind = "0.0.0.0:8080"

workers = 1





# Logging configuration



LOGGING = {

    'version': 1,

    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'formatters': {

        'key_value': {

            'format': 'timestamp=%(asctime)s - name=%(name)s - pid=%(process)d - loglevel=%(levelname)s - %(message)s'

        },

    },

    'handlers': {

        'console': {

            'level': 'INFO',

            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',

            'formatter': 'key_value',

            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'

        },

        "acc_file":{

            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',

            'level': 'INFO',

            'formatter': 'key_value',

            'filename': 'access.log',

            'maxBytes': 10485760,  # 10MB

            'backupCount': 20,

            'encoding': 'utf8',

            'mode': 'a'

        }

    },

    'loggers': {

        'hypercorn.error': {

            'handlers': ['console'],

            'level': 'INFO',

            'propagate': False,

        },

        'hypercorn.access': {

            'handlers': ['console','acc_file'],

            'level': 'INFO',

            'propagate': False,

        }

    },

}



logconfig_dict = LOGGING

accesslog = logging.getLogger('hypercorn.access')

access_log_format = 'senderip=%(h)s - reqdate=%(t)s - statusline="%(r)s" %(st)s - referer="%(f)s" useragent="%(a)s"'

loglevel = "INFO"



As you can see i am providing extra format configuration through the access_log_format variable as per hypercorn docs.
I tried to give it directly to my LOGGING configuration in the format field in one string but it did not work and I don't know why. I'm new to this logging part in python so any references would be amazing.
Also this is my start command:
hypercorn --config file:./hypercorn_conf.py main:redirected_app
